# Rails and fuzzystrmatch PostgreSQL extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In my Rails app I'm search for records that first_name is different from "Mike":

```
Person.last.where("difference(first_name, ?) < 2", "MIKE")
```

but is there any way to use this difference function on `Person` record, not collection to check if some `Person` record has valid `first_name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you know what record you want to check by id:

```
Person.where(
  "id = ? AND difference(first_name, ?) < 2", 5, "MIKE"
).to_sql
#⇒ "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
#      WHERE (id = 5 AND difference(first_name, 'MIKE') < 2)"
```

`to_sql` above is added to demonstrate the query that will be executed and should be removed in real environment.